# How to find the cause of an IllegalStateException Transformation hasn't been executed yet in gradle build

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin

I am at a los of what to do next.  When I try to build my unit tests I get an `IllegalStateException Transformation hasn't been executed yet in gradle build.`

The build output last reported these files as failing:

```
Transform bolts-applinks.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0) with IdentityTransform  

Transform bolts-tasks.jar (com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0) with IdentityTransform    

Transform data-collector.jar (com.paypal.android.sdk:data-collector:2.6.2) with IdentityTransform   

Transform okio.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0) with IdentityTransform
```

But the odd thing is it reports different files each time I try to run unit test.

What steps can I take to figure out why which dependency is causing the problem.  (I presume it's one of the dependencies we are using.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed to upgrade my gradle distribution to at leas 5.2

`https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2-all.zip`

and my mockito dependency to 2.24

`testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.24.0'`

And then my tests built.